# special characters (ö) in ezpdf document

Tags: php, encoding

Im creating a PDF document with ezPDF (version 0.9).

The data I insert in the document is from a MySQL database with encoding: "latin1_swedish_ci".

Special characters (especially ö, which matters the most now) are displayed like Greek pre historical algabra (literal) in the document.

What I have tried so far:

```
iconv();
htmlspecialchars();
htmlentities();
mb_convert_encoding();
utf8_encode();
include with chr(148);
mb_detect_encoding() returns 'UTF-8';
```

All of these wont work, the character is either not displayed or has a strange markup.

What else can I try?

**UPDATE**: Downloaded the new version, problem still remains: See here: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you fetching the data from MySQL as UTF-8? If not,it might be double-encoded already in that step before passing it to the PDF generator?

Have you tried?

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

Edit: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. BUT, beware, the content in the DB might be utf-8 encoded or encoded in any other format no matter what you have set the database to supposedly contain.

Can you show us exactly what characters you get at the various steps?

Edit2:

I downloaded: http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/downloads.php?f=pdfClassesAndFonts_009e.zip from http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/

and run this script in the same dir I unpacked the zip:

```
<?php
include 'class.ezpdf.php';
$pdf = new Cezpdf('a4','portrait');
$pdf->ezText("\xf6\n",0,array('justification'=>'centre'));
$pdf->ezStream();
?>
```

and get a proper ö in the document at least.

if like you said the detected encoding is utf-8, try wrapping a utf8_decode around it:

```
<?php
include 'class.ezpdf.php';
$pdf = new Cezpdf('a4','portrait');
$pdf->ezText(utf8_decode("\xc3\xb6\n"),0,array('justification'=>'centre'));
$pdf->ezStream();
?>
```

If it still doesn't work, maybe you have an older version of ezpdf? It seems they did had to add some fixes for non-ascii characters throughout the times, although long ago.

Comment: In phpmyadmin the ö is displayed right
In a var_dump: �
In the PDF itself: its a ^

Comment: Downloaded the new version, problem still remains:

See here: http://i55.tinypic.com/r1hfnd.jpg

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly there is no way to tell Cezpdf to accept UTF-8 encoded Text. With this snippet you can walkaround this issue:

```
class UTF8_Cezpdf extends Cezpdf {
    function ezText($text, $size=0, $options=array(), $test=0) {
        $text = utf8_decode($text); // or use mb_convert_encoding(), according to your needs
        return parent::ezText($text, $size, $options, $test);
    }
}
```

Of course you have to instantiate the new class insteat of the old one:

```
$pdf = new UTF8_Cezpdf('a4','portrait');
```

One drawback: Text in tables (added via $pdf->ezTable() ) will not be properly encoded.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution. Thank you. In my ancient code there were also addText -function whichi I overwrited. Then fixed all my encoding troubles with ezPDF.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything in this post but without luck. Stumbled upon a blogpost with suggests the following:

Add the following line to functions `ezProcessText()` in `class.ezpdf.php` and `addText()` in `class.pdf.php`:

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

In my case, I just added it to `class.pdf.php`, but it did the trick!

(Source: http://natealberg.wordpress.com/2010/07/26/ezpdf-and-special-characters-copyright-trademark-and-registered-trademark/)

Answer (score 0):

A list of special characters could be found at http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ and just by adding "\x" at the beginning you can get all the special characters in your pdf.

ei:

1. `"\x24"` => `$`
2. `"\x5b"` => `[`

`$pdfObject->ezText("\x5b");` will print `[`